# How to transform array of object to union type of each value in object's property `name`

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have some object like following code, I want to transform array `all` to union type `"a" | "b" | "c"`. Can anyone help me, thank you!!!

```
var a = {
  name: "a",
  id: 0
};
var b = {
  name: "b",
  id: 1
};
var c = {
  name: "c",
  id: 2
};
var all = [a, b, c];
var at = all.map(x => x.name) as const;
type t = typeof at[number];
```

Comment: Can you add the result you expecting?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a const assertion when you are creating the items. With that everything you wrote should work:

```
const a = {
  name: "a" as const,
  id: 0
};
var b = {
  name: "b" as const,
  id: 1
};
var c = {
  name: "c" as const,
  id: 2
};
var all = [a, b, c];
var at = all.map(x => x.name); //("a" | "b" | "c")[]  
type t = typeof at[number]; // "a" | "b" | "c"
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gWAFAxmOBbAUwC4YAiOU+CGUSKAGk2wEsATEgBkwF8BuTAG5wATjABGSVExz5iZMZTjVa0RlhhsSARh78MQ0cEnp1uQiVLBFy8KumaYAJl2CR8ADbvJAbTj1x-sAAunoG8LDIcJ4AdHhwAA4AFAAeSAB8MMnRZgQAlLwwAPSFieSUAD7yFWRWud5B2JhQAJ7xBDARHa0EIABm4d5gAK54YgTCIUWFZBQwlaQKczWkQA)